# dynamically loading Brightcove videos loading the player only once

Tags: video.js, brightcove

I am aware that it is possible to load brightcov player dynamically as in this example from brightcov:

https://codepen.io/team/rcrooks1969/pen/JywoKE
(creating a script tag along with the player and instantiating the video onload of the script, something along the lines of)

`s.src = "//players.brightcove.net/{accountID}/{playerID}_default/index.min.js";
s.onload = callback;`

I am loading multiple video into a page, all of them are loaded dynamically and use the same player.
Would there be a way to load that script only once and still be able to use `videoJs('myPlayer')`

I tried to adapt the example but videojs is always undefined,
https://codepen.io/optionsit/pen/LBvXZm?editors=1011
(each button should load a different video with the same player script)

I tried to use Promises as well with no luck, resolving the promise to the onload event of the script would only resolve for the first video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your `initPlayer` function to use the `bc()` function to initialize the player instead of `videojs()`, it will work.

```
initPlayer = function(player){
  // +++ Initialize the player and start the video +++
  myPlayer = bc(player);
  myPlayer.play();
}
```

I tested this by modifying your CodePen to be certain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait till videojs is loaded. Just render buttons disabled and then you can do something like:

```
s.onload = function() { 
  var btns = document.getElementByTagName('button');
  for (i = 0; i < btns.length;i++) {
    btns[i].disabled = false;
  }
  // or with jQuery simply $('button').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I got this, should I initialise my player without controls and activate them on load ?

Comment: You cant initialize player on click when player.js is still loading. You have to do that script onload.